# Delete an Exchange occurence modification / deletion in EWS (i.e. restore an occurence)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In SharePoint, if you delete / modify a single occurrence of a recurring calendar entry nothing is really deleted / modified - instead, a new entry is created telling SP that for a specific date the occurrence doesn't exist or has new parameters.

As such, this can be reversed by deleting the "exception" entry, thus getting the original occurrence back in the calendar.

I'm trying to achieve a similar functionality in Exchange using Exchange Web Service (EWS), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

A "Recurring Master" object (the `Appointment` entry that defines the recurring event) has two collections for exceptions. One contains modifications to specific occurrences (called `ModifiedOccurrences`) while the other contains "deletions" (called `DeletedOccurrences`).

The problem is that both these collections are read only. I can add elements to these lists by updating or deleting specific occurrences (which need to be downloaded separately), but I cannot make a "rollback".

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or is this impossible given the functionality that EWS offers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do a roll back for a modified or deleted occurrence in EWS.  This is consistent with the user experience in Outlook.

Comment: I though it was impossible in SharePoint as well, except it turned out this wasn't exactly true. ;) Which is kind of the reason I was asking...

Comment: In fact it is somehow possible to remove _all_ exceptions and deletions in Outlook: if you modify the pattern in the master.
But I have no idea how to do this using EWS.