# Remove all occurrence exceptions when updating recurrence master with Exchange Web Service

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When I change the pattern of a reccurrence master appointment in Outlook all modified or deleted occurrences are reset.

I try to achieve the same behavior using EWS from .NET using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll.
Unfortunately I did not found any option to remove the exceptions from an existing appointment.
After calling `item.Update` all exceptions retain in Exchange unless they are completely out of range of the new recurrence pattern.

- The collections `ModifiedOccurrences`and `DeletedOccurrences` are read-only and do not provide a method to clear them.
- The change of the `Recurrence` property seem not to cause this behavior automatically.
- I did not find any item action method like "RemovePatternExceptions" or something like that.
- I know that it is impossible to restore single ocurrences to their default ([Delete an Exchange occurence modification / deletion in EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978212/delete-an-exchange-occurence-modification-deletion-in-ews-i-e-restore-an-occ))

How to restore *all* occurrences using EWS?

Comment: Are you trying to discard all the occurrences that are deleted and modified (1st line from ur post)? OR are you trying to restore all occurrences(last line from your post)?

Comment: I tried to update the pattern from Weekly to Daily using EWS Managed API and it did seem to reset all the occurrences. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-update-a-recurring-series-by-using-ews-in-exchange. The key is to use the item ID of the series' recurring master.

Comment: Yes I do so. If it is a *major* change then exceptions are reset. But if I change e.g. the start date then they are kept, sometimes. Exceptions are identified by their index. And they must not change the sequence. So changing the start time can have almost undefined effects. I guess only exceptions that fail some validation are reset.
Outlook raises a warning and restores all occurrences to their default.
If I write the master from external system I need also defined behavior in case of changes (preferably the same behavior than Outlook). Otherwise the databases will get out of sync.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example in terms of what parameters you changed in outlook and it reset all occurrences but when u tried the same using EWS it didn't update?

Comment: I will try with the Start Date but a reproducible example in the post would be better. which will save the time who are trying to provide you with a solution.

Comment: 1. Recurrent master repeated for 5 days. 2. Exception at the third occurrence. 3. Change Master Start date to start at the day before (now 6 ocurrences).
=> The behavior of Outlook and OWA is also inconsistent.
Outlook: all ocurrences are reset to their default. OWA: the modified occurrence remains.

Comment: which means EWS and OWA are consistent. Also, if you look at it they are the desired use cases. Outlook Desktop Client here is the culprit that needs a fix.

Comment: if you want to make EWS and Outlook consistent. Delete and Create New Appointment is the only possible solution i could think of

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

After extesive inspection it turned out that
**there is no direct way to do this via EWS, but a work around exists.**

## Details

### Exchange server behavior

The EWS API provides no interface to restore existing exceptions.

Wenn an recurrence master is updated the EWS server only discard exceptions that are no longer valid with the new master, e.g. because they are out of scope due to end date changed.
The exact behavior may depend on the Exchance version (untested). In my case it was Exchange 2016.

### Outlook Web Access

Outloook web access seem to expose the native behavior of the Exchange server.
If you do changes to the recurrence master, e.g. move the start date, a warning pops up that this will reset all occurrence exceptions.
**This warning ist wrong.** The exceptions persist unless they have become invalid.

Outlook in contrast shows the same warning and really restores all occurences to their default.

## Work around

The feature that Exchange removes invalid occurrence exceptions can be used to delete all of them.
**Simple disable recurrence temporarily.**

I.e. the appointment need to be updated twice. In the first call only the Recurrence property is cleard. The second update applies the intended changes.

```cs
item.Recurrence = null;
item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
// set Recurrence to the new value here and optionally adjust other properties
item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, invitationsMode);
```

To avoid duplicate change invitations to the attendees of meetings none are sent in the first step.
*It is essential that no further changes are made before the first `Update` call.*
Otherwise required invitations might be lost, e.g. to new or removed attendees.

Comment: Good Alternative. Creating a new `Recurrence ` always restores it. I verified by changing the pattern from weekly to daily. but never thought if we keep the same pattern and just create a new recurrence it could have solved the problem.

Comment: Just curious... Are the first two steps really necessary.. with recurrence setting to null and updating it.. what if u just create a new `Recurrence` and update the appointment? Won't it work?

Comment: Wether you create a new Recurrence or not has no effect on the XML in the EWS API call. In fact I always create a new Recurrence. My worker class does not specify this property to be read from EWS.